# 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Location'

Tags: c#, zooming, eventargs

I want to zoom a chart

```
 private void toolStripButtonZoom_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    double posXStart = chartMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 0.5;
    double posXFinish = chartMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 0.5;
    double posYStart = chartMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 0.5;
    double posYFinish = chartMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 0.5;

    chartMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
    chartMain.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
}
```

it does not recognize "Location" and gives this error.

Comment: In which event do you have this code?

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanitory. `e` is of type `EventArgs` which does not have a property called `Location`. You may be attaching to the wrong event.

Comment: Can you post the signature of the function e.g. `public void OnZoom(EventAgrs e)` including any namespaces you are `using` in the .cs file? Bascially the EventArgs type you are using in that method does not contain a property called `Location`, which implies that the wrong type is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message is correct. The [`EventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) class, an instance of which you're accessing through the `e` parameter, does not contain a `Location` property.

Unfortunately, that's all you get with the `Click` event. You need to switch to handling the `MouseClick` event instead, which passes a [`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) object with a `Location` property. This is rather simple to do, you only need to update the name of the handler method and the code that attaches your handler to the event (possibly located in the designer-generated code-behind file).

Alternatively, you can retrieve the current location of the mouse pointer using the [`Cursor.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current.aspx) property. This is often "good enough", but do keep in mind a couple of things:

1. The `Click` event is not only raised in response to mouse events, but also in certain other cases, like when the control is focused and the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. In those cases, the current location of the mouse pointer may be completely meaningless.

   That's why the `MouseClick` event is a better option. Not only does it give you the location information for free, but it is *only* raised in response to mouse events, when the `Location` property will be meaningful.
2. The user could have moved the mouse between the time that the `Click` event was generated and the time that your event handler executes, which means that `Cursor.Current` returns a different location than where the user originally clicked. In most cases this is not a significant distance, but it could be.

Comment: Helpful, but should be a comment.

Comment: @new I disagree, it did answer the question we were provided. Now that there's more information, I've updated it some more. Note that the original answer was still accurate.